# How do I make my panel to fill the screen down to the footer?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want my panel to take up all the screen until the footer even if the panel is empty.
If the panel is filled I want to scroll to see the content, but the footer should always be visible at the bottom of the page.
Have you got an idea ?
Here is the code :

```css
.list_mobile .footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: lightskyblue;
  color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 mg-tp-xs">
    <div class="panel panel-danger" style="overflow :scroll">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <span>Result</span>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="list_mobile">
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <h4>number of results : 55 </h4>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap has removed all the variants of `*-xs-*` classes. Instead of, `col-xs-12`, use `col-12`. Since  the column is 100% for all sizes, it is enough to use `col-12`.

---

1. Use **`d-flex flex-column h-100`** for the parent of the row.
2. Use **flex-grow-1** for the row.
3. All the parents of row must have 100% height including body and html.
4. **`col-12`** and **`panel`** must have `100%` height.
5. Use a **`row`** for the footer.
6. Do not change position of `footer`: remove `position: absolute; bottom: 0;right: 0;`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column h-100 bg-primary">
  <div class="row flex-grow-1">
    <div class="col-12  bg-danger h-100">
      <div class="panel panel-danger h-100">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <span>Result</span>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>test</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <footer class="col-12 footer">
      <div class="container">
        <h4>number of results : 55 </h4>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

*You can use `container` instead of `container-fluid`*. It does not make any difference. Buy if you do so,remove the container that is in the footer.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container d-flex flex-column h-100 bg-primary">
  <div class="row flex-grow-1">
    <div class="col-12  bg-danger h-100">
      <div class="panel panel-danger h-100">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <span>Result</span>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>test</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <footer class="col-12 footer">
        <h4>number of results : 55 </h4>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the footer is now "stuck" down to the panel, but the panel dosen't take all the height of the page, am i using wrong  on the css, where do i write the 
```html,
body {
  height: 100%;
} ``` ?

Comment: In your custom CSS file. You can also use `h-100` class for the `html` and `body`.

Comment: @SendoTks Didn't it work? If not, what is the problem?

Comment: the panel was not fill down to the footer, sometime where's there is too much result it goes under the footer and i can't see anything, so i've try something else. look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50738690/how-do-i-make-my-scrollable-panel-to-fill-the-entire-screen-down-to-the-footer-w/50738905#50738905

i've tried asking in a new post to be more clear but i look that i was wrong to do that because it's duplication i'm sorry for that,  can i delete the duplicated post  it's just gonna be downvoted ?

Comment: @SendoTks You do something incorrect. Add all of your code including the `body` and `html`  in this question. I will have a look at it.

Comment: i'm in a angularjs view, so i don't have body or html tag on this file, and are you sure ? the code of this file is like 200 lines do you really need to see all the code ?

Comment: @SendoTks You can add a codepen link of it. Have you used component?

Comment: hm idk i'm new on the project and i just start learning front end techno, i'm on a view of the app, so i can show you the code on codepen but it can't show the final result because i don't know what to show in the javascript screen, the view is created using multiples js files. 
https://codepen.io/badis-tks/pen/gKwKQj
it was what you want to see ? (can't share all the css, useless more that thousant lines)

Comment: @SendoTks this answer is correct. There are too many problems with your grid structure. You must learn first how to properly make a [layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). Where have I used `fixed-footer`